# DataReader from objComm.ExecuteReader

Tags: c#, datareader, idatareader

I have the following code and I was wondering if anyone knew the correct way to handle this.

```
SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["someConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand objComm = new SqlCommand("usp_someStoredProcedure", objConn);
objComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
objComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Variable1", VOne);
objComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Variable2", VTwo);

objConn.Open();
using (IDataReader dr = objComm.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Now, let's say the stored procedure returns nothing, is there a method to handle this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Your current code does fine when the SP returns no data.

Comment: "is there a method to handle this": it depends, how do you want the application to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the section you have marked with //do stuff would contain a

```
if (dr.Read())
{
  // do stuff
}
```

or a

```
while (dr.Read())
{
  // do stuff
}
```

The .Read() check ensures that you're only acting if it returned data.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (dr.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));
    }
```

you can refer from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wy5a0f.aspx